# Docker Ubuntu Picking Wrong Directory

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm fairly new to Docker and trying to familarize myself by trying to run a Steam server inside it.

My Dockerfile is as follow:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.10

RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 \ 
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    libgcc1 \
    && apt-get clean autoclean \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p steam/cmd \
    && cd steam \
    && curl -sqL "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz" | tar zxvf - -C cmd

RUN ./steam/cmd/steamcmd.sh +quit
```

I can't figure out why the last step throws this error:

```
Step 4/4 : RUN ./steam/cmd/steamcmd.sh +quit
 ---> Running in c3f673328fe6
./steam/cmd/steamcmd.sh: line 37: /steam/cmd/linux32/steamcmd: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c ./steam/cmd/steamcmd.sh +quit' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Why does `./steam/cmd/steamcmd.sh` gets translated into `/steam/cmd/linux32/steamcmd`?

Step 3/3 isn't placing `steamcmd.sh` inside `linux32`.

```
Step 3/4 : RUN mkdir -p steam/cmd     && cd steam     && curl -sqL "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz" | tar zxvf - -C cmd
 ---> Running in fa5dcd1fcadc
steamcmd.sh
linux32/steamcmd
linux32/steamerrorreporter
linux32/libstdc++.so.6
linux32/crashhandler.so
```

Using `WORKDIR steam/cmd` then following it up with `RUN` returns the same result as well.

Answer (score 3):

See this discussion: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists

Try doing `apt install libc6-i386` as part of step 2.

```
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 \ 
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    ca-certificates \
    libgcc1 \
    libc6-i386 \
    && apt-get clean autoclean \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Also jfyi, the `sh` file is not being "translated" as you think.

If you actually open that `sh`, you will see it tries to call the `linux32` executable (which it calls `$STEAMEXE`).

If you want to be able to fix things like this yourself, here is how I investigated it:

1. I copied your dockerfile, but commented/deleted the last (broken) step.
2. I built the image with `docker build -t helpthiscoder .`
3. I got on the image with `docker start helpthiscoder; docker run -i -t helpthiscoder bash`
4. I looked inside the `sh` file on the image. `apt update; apt install vim; vim /steam/cmd/steamcmd.sh`.
5. Inside this file, I added my own `echo $STEAMEXE` to see that the path was `/steam/cmd/linux32/steamcmd`.
6. I went to `/steam/cmd/linux32` and ran `ls -lah` to see that file was present and executable.
7. I ran `file steamcmd` to get info. Then I saw it was 32-bit.
8. Then I googled `linux 32-bit file not found error Ubuntu 20` and found the link I mentioned in the first paragraph. :/

I get a different error now though:

```
Redirecting stderr to '/root/Steam/logs/stderr.txt'
threadtools.cpp (3787) : Assertion Failed: Probably deadlock or failure waiting for thread to initialize.
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[  0%] Checking for available update...
threadtools.cpp (3787) : Assertion Failed: Probably deadlock or failure waiting for thread to initialize.
Thread failed to initialize
CWorkThreadPool::StartWorkThread: Thread creation failed.
Exiting on SPEW_ABORT
```

I will keep looking into it. I strongly advise you delete your last broken line and build an image that you can "explore" in the way I mentioned above. That's how I'm getting this new error.

Comment: For anyone following up on this answer - the second error seems to be caused by Focal Fossa (Ubuntu 20), which is not supported by steamcmd. Downgrading the man `FROM` to Bionic Beaver (`FROM ubuntu:bionic`) solves it.

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/7190